# Finding the x intercept of a 4th degree polynomial using small increments

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find the x intercept of a 4th degree function by incrementing the x value. I feel like this way doesnt work always and isnt the most efficient way to do this, is there another way I am missing?

My code is:

```
Sub Findintercept()
    Dim equation As Double, x As Double, A As Double, B As Double, C As Double, D As Double, E As Double
    A = 0.000200878
    B = -0.002203704
    C = 0.0086
    D = -0.02333
    E = 0.02033
    x = 0
    equation = A * x ^ 4 + B * x ^ 3 + C * x ^ 2 + D * x + E
    While (equation > 0.00001 Or equation < -0.00001)
        If (x > 5) Then
            MsgBox "Could not find intercept"
            equation = 0
        Else
            x = x + 0.0001
            equation = A * x ^ 4 + B * x ^ 3 + C * x ^ 2 + D * x + E
        End If
    Wend
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

Sometimes it fails to find the intercept hence the IF condition in the while loop. (Im always expecting the intercept to be less than 5!

Comment: Read up on the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). It's simple to code, and you are almost there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method suffers from two problems:

1. You assume a step size to change x. The step could be too large, causing you to "walk past" the value your are looking for. To deal with this, you make a small step size, which can mean an excessively large number of iterations are needed to find the solution.
2. You always assume the same direction to change x. Even with seemingly small values for your step size, you could "walk past" the solution, and have no means to change direction. Or, your initial guess may be on the wrong side of the solution, and you never find an answer.

The [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) handles both of these issues neatly. You do still need to choose your initial guess somewhat close to the root you are looking for.

This method does have potential problems, but for polynomials such as the one you are dealing with, it is quite good.

Below is a simple VBA sub that implements this method. It solves your problem in 4 iterations. I recommend adjusting the initial guess (xii) a lot to see how it impacts the solution you get.

```
Sub SimpleNewtonRaphson()
Const Tol As Double = 1E-06
Const MaxIter As Long = 50
Dim xi As Double, xii As Double, deriv As Double
Dim IterCount As Long
' Initialize
    xi = 0#
    xii = 1#
    IterCount = 0

' Method
    Do While IterCount < MaxIter And Abs(xii - xi) > Tol
        xi = xii
        deriv = myDeriv(xi)
        If deriv = 0# Then Exit Do
        xii = xi - myFunc(xi) / deriv
        IterCount = IterCount + 1
    Loop

' Results
    If deriv = 0 Then MsgBox "Ran into a 0 derivative, modify initial guess"
    If IterCount >= MaxIter Then MsgBox "MaxIterations reached"
    If Abs(xii - xi) <= Tol Then MsgBox "Solution found @" & vbCrLf & "F(" & xii & ") = " & myFunc(xii)

End Sub
```

... and two VBA functions for your equation and it's derivative ...

```
Function myFunc(x As Double) As Double
Const A As Double = 0.000200878
Const B As Double = -0.002203704
Const C As Double = 0.0086
Const D As Double = -0.02333
Const E = 0.02033

myFunc = A * x ^ 4 + B * x ^ 3 + C * x ^ 2 + D * x + E

End Function

Function myDeriv(x As Double) As Double
Const A As Double = 0.000200878
Const B As Double = -0.002203704
Const C As Double = 0.0086
Const D As Double = -0.02333

myDeriv = 4 * A * x ^ 3 + 3 * B * x ^ 2 + 2 * C * x + D

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot!